# Load PDF file in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, pdf

I want to load a pdf file located in upload/grilles/ where upload is located in the root.

My code:

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url()."upload/grilles/".$nomFichier.".pdf"; ?>" target="blank"><?php echo $nomFichier; ?></a>
```

When I click in the link, codeigniter doesn't want to display the document unlike in a site without framework that display.

Why?

Thanks !

Comment: Are you sure of your URL ? Cause of your htaccess, your links will be redirected to index.php if no file / folder exists.

Comment: As Vincent mentioned apparently it's `.htaccess` file issue.
please copy and paste your `.htacess` file which located beside `index.php` file.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a `codeigniter` problem, but a browser (Firefox) issue.

I'd recommend the [PDF.JS library](http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/), which is a general-purpose, web standards-based platform for parsing and rendering PDFs.

**note:** your above example behave (checked on localhost ) in other browsers than FireFox as follows:

*Chrome* Version 34.0.1847.137: shows pdf in new window right away

*IE* 11: asks for permission to show the pdf, if granted shows pdf in new window right away

*Safari* (for windows) 5.1.7.: shows pdf in new window right away

Opera 12.11: shows pdf in new window right away

Answer (score 0):

So....

It's just my URL.

The file name contains a space, but I injected the name in the url which gave:
localhost/xxxx/yyy/file%20test.pdf

but the url's file is:
localhost/xxxx/yyy/file_test.pdf

Sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: did you check it in FF ?

Comment: FF = FireFox, IE= Internet Explorer. Firefox downloads the pdf, while all other browser display the pdf inline, see my answer below